# nginx module: compiles but fails to link a new library

Tags: nginx, compilation, linker, nginx-module

I have modified an nginx module in a way that it depends on a library.... let's call the library that I need libx.

I have modified `auto/os/linux` in such a way that I am able to detect if `libx` is present... by adding something like:

```
+ngx_feature="libx"
+ngx_feature_name="NGX_HAVE_LIBX"
+ngx_feature_run=no
+ngx_feature_incs="#include <libx.h>"
+ngx_feature_path=
+ngx_feature_libs=-lx
+ngx_feature_test="libx_init();"
+. auto/feature
```

Then, in the module code I do `#if`s checking for `NGX_HAVE_LIBX`... something like:

```
#if (NGX_HAVE_LIBX)
   libx_init();
#endif
```

And it works like a charm.... when I run `auto/configure` I get that the library is detected with something like:

```
checking for libx... found
```

and it compiles *BUT* at link time it's not including `-lx` as part of the flags sent to `cc/ld` when building the final `objs/nginx` binary. I would have expected that after the feature be detected in `auto/os/linux` it would *automagically* be added to the linking phase when creating the Makefile... but apparently that's not the case so I know I am missing something... what additional step do I need to do to pull it off?

This is on nginx 1.19.2 (well, `master` branch from nginx mirror).

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.

I needed to add something like this:

```
+ngx_feature="libx"
+ngx_feature_name="NGX_HAVE_LIBX"
+ngx_feature_run=no
+ngx_feature_incs="#include <libx.h>"
+ngx_feature_path=
+ngx_feature_libs=-lx
+ngx_feature_test="libx_init();"
+. auto/feature

if [ $ngx_found = yes ]; then
    CORE_LIBS="$CORE_LIBS -lx"
    NGX_LIBDL="-lx"
fi
```